# msbuild a solution, create web deploy packages for some projects

Tags: c#, asp.net, msbuild

I have a VS 2013 .sln that has multiple ASP.Net projects, a handful of console applications, and some shared libraries. Most (but not all) of the web service projects have a publish profile named "Test". I would like to have these projects (and only these projects) create their web deployment packages when the solution is built. I run into errors when I pass in /p:Configuration=Release;DeployOnBuild=true;DeployTarget=Test since not all of the web services projects will have this publish profile. Any idea how I can achieve what I want?

Thanks!

Comment: Create a new configuration other than `Release` (called `Test` perhaps) and only build the projects you require?